# Artifactory - partial repository sync

Tags: artifactory

I have two instances of artifactory on two separate networks. The two are not connected at all, and only one has an internet connection.

I would like to sync one repository with the other. However, this occurs manually and if I have to transfer entire repositories every time it will be extremely slow. Is there a way to partially export a repository based on date or something like that? The only clue I have so far is that I could access the new artifacts via [artifactory's rest api](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory%27s+REST+API#ArtifactorysRESTAPI-ArtifactsCreatedinDateRange).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ["Artifacts Created in Date Range"](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory%27s+REST+API#ArtifactorysRESTAPI-ArtifactsCreatedinDateRange) REST API query was actually introduced to solve the issue you're facing.

Creating a scheduled task that executes this query and downloads the artifacts provided in the result set is probably your best bet.

Comment: I'm looking in to this. It seems like almost everything will have to be done externally, such as:
- Querying for the new artifacts
- Downloading the artifacts
- Pushing the artifacts to the destination repositories